# Would "The Flash" be able to fly?

Tags: forces

I'm addicted to the new TV program [The Flash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3107288/).

In the last few episodes, the maximum speed required to "beat the bad guys" has been increasing. The most recent episode required him to run at Mach 1.3 (442.37700 m/s).

Given the flash can not only run fast, but move any part of his body at a specified speed, what speed would he need to either:

1) Run

2) Flap his arms

to maintain both:

1) A constant height

2) An increase in height

**TL;DR**

Could I move fast enough to maintain flight??

Comment: Why would you expect that a show about superheroes to have any basis in real-world physics?

Comment: If you take the Flash out of the question, it's a perfectly valid physics question.

Comment: No, it's not really a valid physics question. The human body cannot possibly fly on its own, otherwise we would have been doing it for millennia and have never invented the airplane.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that Flash has a $C_D=1.16$ and an area $S=0.55$ [from this link](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/maher1/)
 and (incorrectly ignoring shock waves) we get:

$$P_{running}=C_d \cdot \frac{1}{2} \rho V^2 S  $$

In numbers: $1.16 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1.225 \cdot 442^2 \cdot 0.55 = 7.6 \cdot 10^4 W
$

The power required to hover is according to [Wiki Momentum theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_theory):

$$P_{hover} = \sqrt{\frac{T^3}{2 \rho A}} $$

With $T=mg$, $A=\pi R^2_{arm}$,
and assuming $m=80 kg$, $R_{arm}=0.75m$ and $\rho=1.225$ we get:

$$P_{hover} = \sqrt{\frac{(80 \cdot 9.81)^3}{2 \cdot 1.225 \cdot \pi \cdot 0.75^2}} = 1.1 \cdot 10^4 W$$

So it seems that for hovering, he has enough power.

Keep in mind that this is for ground level hover (the higher you get the lower the density of air becomes) and many other assumptions, but it might be a good first attempt.